# How does AM radio passive signal boost antenna work?

Tags: antenna

When I was a child I saw advertisements for an AM signal booster which used no batteries or electricity and was simply placed near an AM receiver and a knob turned to tune it. The ads said things like "*turns a tiny transistor [radio] into a tiger!*"

The pictures showed a flat round box about one foot high with the knob in the center. I saw one built with a long piece of wire on an X-shaped frame about a foot high, connected to a tuning capacitor from an old radio. How can this device boost signal strength with no energy input?

Comment: My guess would be make the antenna more tuned to the frequency and thus increase the effective aperture? As most AM radios call "a section of wire that just hangs around a bit" their antenna, there is a lot of room for improvement.

Comment: @JorenVaes it probably does have to do with aperture. Most small radios had / have a ferrite rod antenna, which is very much smaller than this booster device. Someone said, "*The largest room in the world is the room for improvement.*" I spend a lot of time in that room...

Comment: I work with antennas too, tho the dimensions of the ones I build are expressed in micro and millimeters... So what goes on at "DC" is a mystery to me

Comment: @JorenVaes, at DC the bandwidth is rather low, but the propagation is phenomenal :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The booster comprises a high-Q tuned circuit in which the coil has a large loop area.

The large area allows it to capture more signal power than the radio's built-in antenna can, and the fact that it resonates with the signal allows a large current to build up in the coil.

Since the radio is primarily sensitive to the magnetic component of the radio signal anyway, it couples readily to the current flowing in the booster, producing a stronger output than it can on its own.

Also, the high selectivity of the booster helps to eliminate adjacent channel interference, further improving the perceived quality of the signal.

Comment: So, basically it rings like a big wineglass, and causes the nearby smaller wineglass (the radio) to ring also.